# excuting javascript file into the new tab on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to insert a javascript file into the original new tab page of chrome to be executed,
I tried this but error in matching when I'm trying to load the extension.

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["chrome://newtab/*"],
  "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
}
 ]
```

Comment: I don't wanna replace the original 'new tab page' of chrome with a new  one , I just want to execute this javascript code on the original tab of chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that, you need to use [override pages](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/override.html) to do this.

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...

  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "myPage.html"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: I don't wanna replace the original 'new tab page' of chrome with a new  one , I just want to execute this javascript code on the original tab of chrome.

Comment: ok, can I get the thumbnail and links of chrome new tab page??

Comment: Inspect the New Tab page, you will see `chrome://thumb/https://plus.google.com/` for links, you need to use the History API in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your matches: `"matches": ["*://*.google.com/_/chrome/newtab*"]`

That url looks like an implementation detail, so no guarantees it won't change, but for now it works.